# Can I represent my .NET dictionaries as JSON dictionaries in my GraphQL?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, graphql, graphql-dotnet

When I'm serialising to JSON, I'm used to .NET dictionaries becoming objects with the keys as properties and the values as their values. ([The Json.Net docs have a succinct example.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm))

I'm using GraphQL and struggling to achieve a similar result. My data for this root query is basically a `Dictionary<MyEnum,Dictionary<string,string>>`. The closest I've got so far is this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "outterDict": [
      {
        "key": "THING_1",
        "innerDict": [
          {
            "key": "key1",
            "val": "val1"
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      {
        "key": "THING_2",
        "innerDict": [
          {
            "key": "key2",
            "val": "val2"
          },
          ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want it to be closer to this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "collection": {
      "THING_1": {
        "key1": "val1",
        ...
      },
      "THING_2": {
        "key2": "val2",
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm struggling because [GraphQL .Net only seems to understand lists](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/schema-types), not dictionaries.

It doesn't *feel* like what I'm trying to do is unreasonable. Letting keys be keys seems right and like the most useful way to share this data (e.g. as [suggested by this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/321542/28132)).

Is there a way to do this in GraphQL? Is there a way to do this in GraphQL *.Net*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite of lot of research, it seems like this isn't in the spec of GraphQL and [is therefore unsupported in GraphQL.Net](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/826#issuecomment-422486612).

GraphQL expects all possible properties (i.e. keys in a map/dictionary) to be known in advance. This means we lose a lot of the value of passing a dictionary at run time.

So although the GraphQL JSON is more verbose than idiomatic JSON, it's like this deliberately.